# LLVM IR insertion

Tags: llvm

i am trying to insert a very simple instruction into my basic block by the code

```
Value *ten=ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(con),10,true);
Instruction *newinst=new AllocaInst(Type::getInt32Ty(con),ten,"jst");
b->getInstList().push_back(newinst);
Instruction *add=BinaryOperator::Create(Instruction :: Add,ten,ten,"twenty");
b->getInstList().push_back(add);
```

it giving stack dump while i am running it on a very small file:

```
   While deleting: i32 %
```

use still stuck around after Def is Destroyed : `%twenty = add i32 10, 10`

I'm rather new to LLVM, so I'll take any advice if this code makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LLVM instruction constructors and `Create` factories accept either an `Instruction` to insert after, or a `BasicBlock` to insert at the end of. Do not use `getInstList` to do this.

[Here are samples](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1AllocaInst.html) for `AllocaInst`:

```
AllocaInst (Type *Ty, Value *ArraySize=nullptr,
            const Twine &Name="", Instruction *InsertBefore=nullptr)
AllocaInst (Type *Ty, Value *ArraySize,
            const Twine &Name, BasicBlock *InsertAtEnd)
```

Comment: what value is to give for argument  "const Twine &Name" if suppose i want an array of 10 integers

Comment: @techcomp: anything, it's just for debugging purposes. You can just pass in an empty string